# Can you open clients email with an attachment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I am wondering if it is possible to open the outlook of someone on an internal website to send a message with an attachment.

So far I have tried using mailto:

```
<a href="mailto:name@email.com">Link text</a>
```

And this opens outlook for them to send a message but I don't think I can add an attachment to this.

Then I tried

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        oMsg.Subject = "emailSubject";
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        oMsg.BCC = "emailBcc";
        oMsg.To = "emailRecipient";
        oMsg.HTMLBody = "New Body";

        oMsg.Attachments.Add("ATTACHMENTPATH");
        oMsg.Display(false);
```

This works if I run it on my computer but when set up with a website I get this error

[image: ErrorMessage]

I believe this is because it is trying to open it on the server and outlook is not installed on the server.

Is there any way to open it on the clients side and not on the server?

Comment: You cannot use interop on the *server* to launch an email client on the *client*.  The best you can do is a `mailto:` link, which as far as I know, does not support attachments.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but wanted to see if there was another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate an EML (MIME) file on the server and populate its contents with any data you like, including the attachments. Outlook on the client side will be able to open and show it. To make sure it is treated as an unsent message by Outlook, set the `X-Unsent` MIME header to 1.

Comment: Do you know how to add the X-Unsent to a MailItem?

Comment: I'll look into this. Thanks For the answer!

Comment: MailItem.Sent property is read-only - on the MAPI level, that flag is only settable before the first Save, that is why OOM won't let you set it. But when you create a new message, OOM defaults it to unsent, and that is what you want.